# Undefined name AdaptiveAutoRouter used as an annotation

Tags: flutter, routes

I keep on getting this error (Android Studio).

`lib/routes/router.dart`:

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:salomon_routing_tutorial/home_page.dart';
...
@AdaptiveAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
...
```

`pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: salomon_routing_tutorial
description: Flutter Bottom Navigation with Nested Routing Tutorial.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  auto_route: ^6.0.5
  salomon_bottom_bar: ^3.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.4
  auto_route_generator: ^6.0.3
  build_runner: ^2.1.2
  analyzer: ^5.10.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

A typo should be out of the question, the name in question is copied from a working project. What could it be?

Comment: Have you already tried to run build_runner ?

Comment: Of course. It says something like `[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 31ms

[INFO] Succeeded after 64ms with 0 outputs (2 actions)`

Comment: Hi @Alexey Orlov please try the below answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

1. Delete your router.dart and router.gr.dart (if created) file
2. Create a file app_router.dart and copy below code.

   ```
   import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';       
   part 'app_router.gr.dart';

   @AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route')
   class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {

     @override      
     RouteType get defaultRouteType => const RouteType.adaptive(); //.cupertino, .adaptive ..etc 

    @override
    final List<AutoRoute> routes = [
     //routes here
    ];
   }
   ```

save and run build_runner

Comment: This is from the docs, I know. The trouble is, I have a working project organized just like in the present case, no problem with it. The subject error is the first one, so it should be relevant. The AdaptiveAutoRouter name must exist, in any case.

Comment: Oh, yes. `auto_route` jumped from v2 to v6. Everything changed :( . (Almost) total rewrite is in order, or so I gather...

Comment: Please remove SPACE staring at Route. '@AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: 'Page, Route')'

Comment: well , more example for routes here cause we cant just use screenpage, can you ?```AutoRoute(page: SplashScreen, initial: true),
    AutoRoute(page: OnBoardingScreen),```