# app_router.gr not generated on run_builder command

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create an appRouter using auto_router. I started according to the instructions, with a basic appRouter:

```
import 'package:auto_route/annotations.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';

part 'app_router.gr.dart';

@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {

  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
    /// routes go here
  ];
}
```

Running `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` generated the @JsonSerializable models, but not the appRouter. What goes wrong?

pubsec.yaml:

ersion: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'

````
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  android_alarm_manager_plus: ^3.0.2
  alarm: ^1.1.5

  shared_preferences: ^2.1.1
  audioplayers: ^4.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^14.1.0
  flutter_background_service: ^5.0.1
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.2
  image: ^4.0.17
  flutter_timezone: ^1.0.6
  android_long_task: ^1.0.0
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  bloc: ^8.1.2
  flutter_form_builder: ^9.1.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0
  dio: ^5.3.2
  jwt_decode: ^0.3.1
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
  get_it: ^7.6.0
  auto_route: ^7.8.3
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1```

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
````

Comment: try this command `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75931673/14071053